# Cannot access apache using http://localhost on firefox

Tags: firefox, localhost

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 and I haven't modified any Apache files. There is an entry `127.0.0.1 localhost` in my /etc/hosts file.

My problem is that when I try to access my Apache server using `http://localhost` or just `localhost` in Firefox, it returns a "Server Not Found" message. The header error is `NS_ERROR_UNKNOWN_HOST`. But I can access it using `http://127.0.0.1`

Also `http://localhost` and `http://127.0.0.1` work fine in Chrome.

My Firefox version is 67.0.1 and I have switched off any proxy servers. I have tried this in Firefox Developer Edition also and I get the same error.

Using `nslookup localhost` gives these values

```
Server:     192.168.1.1
Address:    192.168.1.1#53
```

Seems like those are pointing to my router. Where do I change those values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out that my /etc/network/interfaces was setup with old values.. I just changed it to the defaults and its working alright now